# tbl_uvregression or tbl_regression into PDF

Tags: gtsummary

i whish to save my tbl_uvregressions into a pdf file to easily share the outcomes with collegues, but I cannot find the right code for this. Does anybody know how this should be done? Thanks in advance!

I've tried as.pdf(), write.pdf and pdf(), but that didnt work. Do I need to change the tbl_uvregression into another table first?

Comment: See this tutorial for examples https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg, following those examples, it gives me the following error: 

tbl_summary(uvregressie_sia) %>%
+   as_flex_table()
Error in UseMethod("ungroup") : 
  no applicable method for 'ungroup' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_uvregression', 'gtsummary')"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll need to update your post with a minimal reproducible example (https://reprex.tidyverse.org/), that is code with data we can run on our machines.